# Extract Months and Years list from the Date field in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

[Database Image**strong text**][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.i**strong text**mgur.com/0Otet.png

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please check the preview of your post before posting. In this case, the images in your post is not formatted properly and there are multiple unnecessary **strong texts**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.